# Excessive drooling for infant

Tags: infant

My infant has started drooling a lot since about 12 weeks old. I thought it may have been due to teething but he is now 16 weeks old and I see no teeth and don't believe he's begun teething yet. Is there a reason for this?

Is this a prediction of teething ?

Comment: Even though it has been 4 weeks, this could still be a sign of teething. Is he showing any other signs? Or just drooling?

Comment: @BriHan Drooling and putting his hands in his mouth!

Answer (score 2):

Some children just drool more than others, though it can be a result of teething as well.  Source: my pediatrician when I was concerned that my son was still wearing bibs close to three years of age.  He's almost four now and still a drooler at times, lol.

Answer (score 2):

Teething can take a while, and excessive drooling can accompany it. Both my kids started drooling months (maybe 2-3?) before the first teeth were visible.

Given that there are a number of teeth that develop it can happen that a kids drools a lot for a longer time.